# How to get an attribute from an element within other one element using PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I am trying to get the attribute src from img within of description element with the code below.

All this is working correctly

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

for ($i=0; $i<=7; $i++) {
  $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

  // Here is where is the mistake

  $item_url_img = $x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');

  $new = new NewFCB();
  $new->link = $item_link;
  $new->title = $item_title;
  $new->description = $item_desc;
  $new->imgUrl = $item_url_img;

  $listNews[] = $new;
}
```

This is the xml estructure that I'm reading. The `img` is inside the 
I am trying to get the `img` inside the `description` element.

```
<item>
    <title>Digne, baja por unas molestias en la rodilla</title>
    <link>
        http://www.sport.es/es/noticias/barca/digne-baja-por-unas-molestias-    rodilla-5777073?utm_source=rss-noticias&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=barca
    </link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 31 Jan 2017 13:45:39 +0200</pubDate>
    <description>
        <p>Lucas Digne&#160;no se desplazará con el resto de la plantilla     del&#160;Barça&#160;al&#160;Vicente Calderón&#160;para la disputa del partido     de ida de las semifinales de&#160;Copa&#160;frente al&#160;Atlético Madrid.     El defensa francés es baja en la ...</p><a     href="http://www.sport.es/es/noticias/barca/digne-baja-por-unas-molestias-    rodilla-5777073?utm_source=rss-    noticias&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=barca">leer la noticia completa</a>    <br/>            
        <img alt="" src="http://estaticos.sport.es/resources/jpg/7/8/jordi-alba-viajara-con-equipo-calderon-1485865523987.jpg"/>
    </description>
    <guid>
    http://www.sport.es/es/noticias/barca/digne-baja-por-unas-molestias-        rodilla-5777073?utm_source=rss-noticias&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=barca
    </guid>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Xpath expressions to fetch the nodes and values:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
  $row = [
    'title' => $xpath->evaluate('string(title)', $item),
    'link' => $xpath->evaluate('string(link)', $item),
    'description' => $xpath->evaluate('string(description)', $item),
    'image-src' => $xpath->evaluate('string(description/img/@src)', $item)
  ];
  var_dump($row);
}
```

However in RSS description often contains a HTML snippet as a text node or cdata section. In this case you would have to load it into a fragment node and use Xpath on it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure, but I think, the error is with

```
->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->
```

The second `item(0)` gives you the the `p` element, which is closed before the `img` element, and therefore cannot include it.

---

Maybe, you want to consider [XPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php), which could give you the `src` attribute by

```
/item/description/img/@src
```

or similar (my XPath-fu is a bit rusty).

Comment: A little :-) - `[rss]` would be a CSS attribute selector. `@src` or `attribute::src` would be the Xpath location path.